# Not able to generate new file properly with batch scripting

Tags: batch, batch-file

I'm trying to get a specific file (which is in the current directory) to run in the background. To do this I am using batch script to make a file called file12.vbs , which will run file1.bat in the background. The problem is that file12.vbs isn't generating with all 3 lines of the code bellow. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
echo Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")>> file12.vbs
echo WshShell.Run chr(34) & "file1.bat" & Chr(34), 0>> file12.vbs
echo Set WshShell = Nothing>> file12.vbs`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Not able to generate new file properly with batch scripting**

I was able to get it to work using this syntax using the caret `^` symbol to [escape characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

```
IF EXIST file12.vbs DEL /Q /F file12.vbs
(
echo Set WshShell = CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
echo WshShell.Run chr^(34^) ^& "file1.bat" ^& Chr^(34^), 0
echo Set WshShell = Nothing
)>> file12.vbs
```

### Further Resources

- [Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)

Comment: That's a good point, I put `IF EXIST` logic up top for it to be deleted so if the OP needs it to be deleted first it will be before it's appended to. Additionally, you can just use `> file12.vbs` and remove the `IF EXIST` logic. I just left that part as it was per the example in the question.